# byte array[] to byte is it possible in java?

Tags: java, byte, arrays

I know in java we can't deal with bit directly, I want to know how can we convert an byte array[] to byte. Such that

```
String bytestr="00000011";
byte[] noofbytes=bytestr.getBytes();
byte convbyte=(noofbytes[]) to byte
```

Is it possible ? does any one have any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to interpret "00000011" as "decimal 3"?

Comment: `Byte.valueOf(bytestr,2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean *bits*, not bytes.

```
String bitstr = "00000011";
byte convbyte = Byte.parseByte(bitstr, 2);
```

The `, 2` tells it that you're parsing a binary (base 2) string; the default would be decimal (base 10).

Comment: Actually i was looking for byte[] to byte, but now i didn't need that,above one solved my problem.@T.J.Crowder accepted.